With two reagents common on Mars, fluorite and CO2, how would I produce carbon tetrafluoride?
The hypothetical terraforming of Mars would require the heating of the atmosphere. A commonly suggested method is the in-situ production of fluorocarbons, powerful greenhouse gases.
For example, Marinova et al estimate as little as 0.2 Pa of a mixture of greenhouse gases ($\ce{CF4, C2F6, C3F8}$ and $\ce{SF6}$) would produce enough heating to trigger a runaway greenhouse effect by evaporating $\ce{CO2}$ at the south pole of Mars. There is some dispute about whether there is sufficient carbon dioxide on Mars, but that is another issue.
Fluorine is abundant in the regolith of Mars, at about 0.8 - 2.5 wt%, in the form of fluorite and fluorapatites. Mars' atmosphere is 95% carbon dioxide, although at a pressure of 0.006 atm (600  Pa). These seem the appropriate reactants.
For simplicity, I am interested in the reaction:
$\ce{2CaF2 + CO2 -> CF4 + 2CaO}$
This is energetically unfavorable. I calculated the enthalpy of the reaction at +646 kJ/mol, assuming $\ce{CO2}$ & $\ce{F2}$ are both at 1 atm. (I may have made an error - please check if you would like.) Simply assume that high-purity fluorite is available on Mars (as acidspar) and that carbon dioxide can readily be fractionated to near 100% purity and compressed. Also assume appropriate industrial infrastructure can be built on Mars, including the required power supply, and that any catalysts can be easily imported or found on Mars.
AFAIK this reaction is not used for industrial fluorocarbon production. Given the readily available $\ce{CO2}$ (on Earth) that suggests it is not attractive. However, other resources used in fluorocarbon production may not be available on Mars, although I'm open to suggestions.
Is there a way to make it work?
This question is related to my answer here.

The problem, as always, is not within chemistry. The real problem is "where is the money".

Another problem is "would it make sense".

Thanks Mithoron for the editing. How do you get the chemical formulas out of the italics I used?
Also can you suggest someone with expertise in this area?

https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/faq-how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange BTW @ right before username pings.

I'm just interested in chemical feasibility. Let's say Elon Musk is obsessed in terraforming Mars and is willing to throw whatever it takes at the problem for the betterment of mankind and his ego. How would you do it?

https://web.archive.org/web/20130216164759/http://www.climatevision.gov/sectors/aluminum/pdfs/tmsfirst.pdf

Thanks Mithron. I possibly need to find bauxite on Mars! I'll look at it tomorrow. It's past bedtime for me in Sydney. It look like < 1 kg/tonne Al produced. Maybe their are hints to maximising fluorocarbon output or another chemistry
